# How to insert, update, delete when import data from table to table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a query that I need to run more than once a day. This query is importing data from a database to another.

The target table structure is:

```
Id   Date        Department  Location  PersonId  Starttime       EndTime       State
1    2012-01-01      2           5       200     12:00:00.000    15:00:00.000   2
```

An application can also insert data to the target table. The records that are inserted by the application may not be updated also when this record exists in the source(temp table) table with another state.

To make this possible I have an solution created. I will create an new column in the target table with a second state so that I can check.

```
Id   Date        Department  Location  PersonId  Starttime       EndTime       State   StateSource
1    2012-01-01      2           5       200     12:00:00.000    15:00:00.000   2       2
```

Some Requirements:

If a record is added by the application than StateSource will be NULL. Means that this record may not be deleted, updated or inserted again from the source table.

If a Record is updated by the application than the value State and StateSource will be different. In this case I do not update this record.

I will update if the state from the sourcetable and targettable are not same and the values from target table State = StateSource.

I will INSERT a record when this is not exists in the target table. When records already exists do not insert (no matter if this is added by the application or my query on the first run).

I will delete the records from the target when they are no more exists in my sourcetable and State=StateSource.

I already have the following queries. I have decided to make 3 statements.

```
--Delete Statement first
Delete from t
from TargetTable t LEFT JOIN SourceTable s ON t.Id=s.Id 
and t.Date=s.Date 
and t.departments=s.Department
and t.PersonId=s.PersonId
and t.State=t.StateSource

--Just delete if a date is no more exists from the source table and this records is NOT
--changed by the application (t.State=t.StateSource)


--Update statement second
Update t
set t.State = s.State
From Targettable t INNER JOIN SourceTable s ON t.Id=s.Id 
and t.Date=s.Date 
and t.departments=s.Department
and t.PersonId=s.PersonId

The problem here is:
--when I have State 2 already in the targettable and in my sourcetable i have
--another state then the state in the targettable changes. This would not be the case.


--Insert Statement thirth

insert into TargetTable (Id, Date, Department, Location, PersonId, Starttime, EndTime,State, StateSource)
select Id, Date, Department, Location, PersonId, Starttime, EndTime,State, StateSource
from SourceTable s 
WHERE Date not in (select Date 
                   from TargetTable t 
                   where t.id=s.id 
                   and t.PersonId=s.PersonId
                   and t.date=s.date
                   and t.department=s.department)     

--I have no idea about how the insert should be because the application also can
--insert records. When a record exists then no insert. What to do with the State?
```

Remember that the states that are changed by the application are leading.

Can anyone help me with the desired result?

Comment: you are deleting all data that is not from application inserted/updated... then changing all state of what was application inserted/updated... then inserting all that is not application inserted/updated.. your state field is like to mean when it was updated? like a update version?

Answer (score 0):

you may use a merge statement.. something like this...

```
with target_T as (select * from UR_TARGET_TABLE
                  where statesource is not null) -- to dont change the data inserted from application...
merge target_T as TARGET
using UR_SOURCE_TABLE as SOURCE
on SOURCE.id = TARGET.id    -- id is unique? anyway, put your primary key here...

when matched and TARGET.state = TARGET.statesource then --if inserted/updated from application, will not change data
update set TARGET.state = SOURCE.state
          ,TARGET.statesource = SOURCE.state  --important update it together to be different from an application update
        --, other collumns that you have to set...

--should use another when matched then update if need to change something on inserted/updated from application data


when not matched by TARGET then
         insert (Id, Date, Department, Location, PersonId, Starttime, EndTime,State, StateSource)
         values(SOURCE.Id, SOURCE.Date, SOURCE.Department, SOURCE.Location, SOURCE.PersonId, SOURCE.Starttime, SOURCE.EndTime,SOURCE.State, SOURCE.StateSource);
```

if you set an sample with declaring your tables and inserting some data...

I should help more, with a code that really works.. not just a sample...