# Merge two records when state is changed in a update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a update statement  that will change the state in a tableA from TableB. The data in this table is like:

```
Serial   PersonId    Date        Department    State      Begintime    Endtime
    1       1        2012-01-01      50          1        08:00        11:00
    2       1        2012-01-01      50          5        11:00        14:00
```

When I get State 2 from tableB then I need to set the states of the both records to: 2 but I want have just one record for each state.

The result should be:

```
Serial   PersonId    Date        Department    State     Begintime     Endtime
    1       1        2012-01-01      50          2       08:00         14:00
```

Vice versa also must be possible:
TableA contains:

```
Serial   PersonId    Date        Department    State     Begintime     Endtime
    1       1        2012-01-01      50          2       08:00         14:00
```

After the update I would like to have: (this two records are coming from tableB)

```
Serial   PersonId    Date        Department    State      Begintime    Endtime
    1       1        2012-01-01      50          1        08:00        10:00
    2       1        2012-01-01      50          5        12:00        15:00
```

I also don't know if this need to be updated with a update statement.
Any ideas to solve this?

I'm using sql server 2005.

Comment: An update can't remove rows or add them, so it won't work. You're going to need to write a stored procedure to do this, and to put multiple statements in a transaction. This structure doesn't feel like a good design, though.

Comment: @Laurence, thank you. I don't have an idea which statements and how the stored procedure should be look like. Any idea?

Comment: If you're able to move up to SQL 2008 then you can use the MERGE statement to get a lot of the way there. You probably need to flesh out the question a bit more-maybe a bit of context as to why this updating is happening? From what I can understand I think you'll need some sort of a staging table because if you're updating A then it's hard to then use A to update B - assuming this is a batch process.

Comment: But, if this is to happen in 'real time' then perhaps triggers are the way to go.  However @Laurence has made a good point - a stored proc would encapsulate a lot of this nicely and is more discoverable than a trigger.  But if whatever's populating the table can't be made to call a stored proc then well written triggers (ones that handle multiple records) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmet, would this work for you?

```
INSERT INTO tableA a
SELECT * FROM tableB b
WHERE b.[State] NOT IN (
    SELECT [State] FROM tableA
)
```

I'm assuming that you're wanting to copy new records between tables.

Comment: See: [My other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248976/how-to-insert-update-delete-when-import-data-from-table-to-table). I have this insert statement already. Thank you. Do you other suggestions than what I have in the link above?